# Proof $f(x,y)=xy(x^2-y^2)/(x^2+y^2)$ continuous everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x,y)=xy(x^2-y^2)/(x^2+y^2)$ with $f(0,0)=0$.
The question was asking to proof $f(x,y)$ continuous everywhere.
One way to solve it was to just change $x=r\cos(\theta),y=r\sin(\theta)$ and solved it.

First question:
However, is there is a way to just solve it through $x,y$ without the transformation of coordinates?

Second question:
Second, I computed $f_x=\frac{y(x^2+y^2)-xy(2x)}{x^2+y^2}$,$f_y=\frac{x(x^2+y^2)-xy(2y)}{x^2+y^2}$. How to proof $f$ was continuous through the Corollary that: if all the first partial derivatives of $f$ exists and are continuous in an open set $D$, then $f$ itself is continuous in $D$.

Comment: I don't understand your second question ? Do you want to study continuity of $f_x,f_y$ or do you want a proof of the theorem ?

Comment: The Corollary was known, how to proof $f_x$ and $f_y$ was continuous everywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go back to the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition.

You don't need to actually transform to polar but, it is almost the same thing.

let $d((0,0),(x,y)) = \|\mathbf x \| = $ be the Euclidean metric.

$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta >0 : \|\mathbf x\|<\delta \implies |f(x,y) |<\epsilon.$

$x^2 +y^2 = \|\mathbf x\|^2\\
x^2 -y^2 < \|\mathbf x\|^2\\
xy < \frac 12 \|\mathbf x\|^2$

$f(x,y) < \frac {\delta^2}{2}$

let $\delta = \sqrt {2\epsilon}$

Comment: Can you please tell me why xy< 1/2 the square of the Euclidean metric?

Comment: $(x-y)^2 > 0 \implies x^2 + y^2 - 2xy > 0\implies \frac 12 (x^2+y^2) > xy$

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

An alternate method is to write $y=mx$, with $m=m(x,y)$ is variable, or if you prefer $m=y/x$, what is important is to study how fast $y$ goes to $0$ compared to $x$.

$\displaystyle f(x,y)=\frac{xy\;x^2(1-m^2)}{x^2(1+m^2)}=xy\;\frac{1-m^2}{1+m^2}=xy.\phi(m)$

But $\phi(m)$ being bounded on $\mathbb R$, $f(x,y)\to 0$ when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$.

---

You can apply same method for $f_x$ and $f_y$ (*note that you miscalculated them*).

$\displaystyle f_x(x,y)=\frac{y(x^4-y^4+4x^2y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=\frac{yx^4(1-m^4+4m^2)}{x^4(1+m^2)^2}=y\;\frac{1-m^4+4m^2}{(1+m^2)^2}$

$\displaystyle f_y(x,y)=\frac{x(x^4-y^4-4x^2y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=\frac{x^5(1-m^4-4m^2)}{x^4(1+m^2)^2}=x\;\frac{1-m^4-4m^2}{(1+m^2)^2}$

Again the fractions containing $m$ are bounded (it is easy to see there is no problem on denominator, and limits in $0$ and $\infty$ exists), so $f_x(x,y)\to 0$ and $f_y(x,y)\to 0$ when $(x,y)\to (0,0)$.

And since there are no problems in other points, $f_x,f_y$ are continuous everywhere.